# Winsock File damaged After Transfer in C++

Tags: c++, ftp, winsock

Here is my problem, I have tested a File Transfer Function with the client and server on the same machine and everything works fine.

But when I tried using it locally on a different machine, the file I receive is damaged. The size seems to be the same but when I open it with a hex editor, the files are slightly different(Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/15XBM.png)

Server

```
void fileSend(SOCKET theSocket, string filePath)
{
    ifstream fichier;
    fichier.open(filePath, ios::binary);
    int cumul = 0;
    int size = BUFF_SIZE;
    char szBuf[BUFF_SIZE];
    int nRet;

    //Used to find and send the size of the file   
    fichier.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int taille = fichier.tellg();

    // int --> char*
    sprintf_s(szBuf, "%d", taille);

    nRet = send(theSocket,                      // Connected socket
        szBuf,                             // Data buffer
        sizeof(szBuf),                     // Buffer length
        0);                                 // Flags

    fichier.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    // Send Packets of size 256 per (BUFF_SIZE)
    while (cumul < taille)
    {
        //Adjust when we are at the last packet
        if ((taille - cumul) < BUFF_SIZE)
            size = (taille - cumul);

        fichier.read(szBuf, size);

        // Send the Packet
        nRet = send(theSocket,        // Connected socket
            szBuf,                    // Data buffer
            size,                     // Buffer length
            0);                       // Flags

        if (nRet != -1)
            cumul += nRet;
        memset(szBuf, 0, sizeof(szBuf));
    }
    fichier.close();
}
```

Client

```
void fileReceive(SOCKET theSocket, char* fileName)
{
    ofstream fichier;
    fichier.open(fileName, ios::binary | ios::beg);
    int cumul = 0;
    int size = BUFF_SIZE;
    char szBuf[BUFF_SIZE];
    int nRet;

    // We receive the size of the File
    nRet = recv(theSocket,                   // Connected socket
        szBuf,                 // Receive buffer
        sizeof(szBuf),       // Size of receive buffer
        0);                    // Flags
    if (nRet == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(theSocket);
        return;
    }

    // Char* -> int
    int taille = atoi(szBuf);

    // Receive Packets per size of 256 (BUFF_SIZE)
    while (cumul < taille)
    {
        //When on the last Packet, adjust size
        if ((taille - cumul) < BUFF_SIZE)
            size = (taille - cumul);

        // Recevoir le paquet
        nRet = recv(theSocket,      // Connected socket
            szBuf,                  // Data buffer
            size,                   // Lenght of data
            0);                     // Flags

        if (nRet != -1)
        {
            cumul += nRet;
            fichier.write(szBuf, size);
        }
        memset(szBuf, 0, sizeof(szBuf));
    }
    fichier.close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "slightly different"?  Show us what you mean (what you're sending vs what you're receiving).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/9YNFNxx.png Screenshot of both Side by side, Left is the Original, Right is the Sent (corrupted one)

Comment: In your client, shouldn't `fichier.write(szBuf, size);` be `fichier.write(szBuf, nRet);` ? Your `size` is not guaranteed to be filled; that's somewhat the whole point of `nRet`. I also suspect a test-for-zero should be in there as well, but properly using `nRet` will probably make that moot.

Comment: Haha, only by changing that line, everything worked. Thanks a lot man